# How to base64 encode special json string in golang?

Tags: json, go, base64

I need to encode the following string through base64 in golang

`"{\n\t\"signature\" = \"ZwXG56AezlHRTBhL8cTqA==\";\n\t\"purchase-info\" = \"RXRjL0dNVCI7Cn0=\";\n\t\"environment\" = \"Sandbox\";\n\t\"pod\" = \"100\";\n\t\"signing-status\" = \"0\";\n}"`

I try to do it as below

```
rec = []byte("{\n\t\"signature\" = \"ZwXG56AezlHRTBhL8cTqA==\";\n\t\"purchase-info\" = \"RXRjL0dNVCI7Cn0=\";\n\t\"environment\" = \"Sandbox\";\n\t\"pod\" = \"100\";\n\t\"signing-status\" = \"0\";\n}")
str := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(rec)
fmt.Println(str)
```

Output

`ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiWndYRzU2QWV6bEhSVEJoTDhjVHFBPT0iOwoJInB1cmNoYXNlLWluZm8iID0gIlJYUmpMMGROVkNJN0NuMD0iOwoJImVudmlyb25tZW50IiA9ICJTYW5kYm94IjsKCSJwb2QiID0gIjEwMCI7Cgkic2lnbmluZy1zdGF0dXMiID0gIjAiOwp9`

However, it failed. Because the result is different with the base64 result through https://www.base64encode.org/, which is

`e1xuXHRcInNpZ25hdHVyZVwiID0gXCJad1hHNTZBZXpsSFJUQmhMOGNUcUE9PVwiO1xuXHRcInB1cmNoYXNlLWluZm9cIiA9IFwiUlhSakwwZE5WQ0k3Q24wPVwiO1xuXHRcImVudmlyb25tZW50XCIgPSBcIlNhbmRib3hcIjtcblx0XCJwb2RcIiA9IFwiMTAwXCI7XG5cdFwic2lnbmluZy1zdGF0dXNcIiA9IFwiMFwiO1xufQ==`

Then I try it in this way

```
data1 := []byte(`{\n\t\"signature\" = \"ZwXG56AezlHRTBhL8cTqA==\";\n\t\"purchase-info\" = \"RXRjL0dNVCI7Cn0=\";\n\t\"environment\" = \"Sandbox\";\n\t\"pod\" = \"100\";\n\t\"signing-status\" = \"0\";\n}`)
str1 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(data1)
fmt.Println(str1)
```

Output:

`e1xuXHRcInNpZ25hdHVyZVwiID0gXCJad1hHNTZBZXpsSFJUQmhMOGNUcUE9PVwiO1xuXHRcInB1cmNoYXNlLWluZm9cIiA9IFwiUlhSakwwZE5WQ0k3Q24wPVwiO1xuXHRcImVudmlyb25tZW50XCIgPSBcIlNhbmRib3hcIjtcblx0XCJwb2RcIiA9IFwiMTAwXCI7XG5cdFwic2lnbmluZy1zdGF0dXNcIiA9IFwiMFwiO1xufQ==`

Now the result is correct.

How to convert the original string from

```
[]byte("{\n\t\"signature\" = \"ZwXG56AezlHRTBhL8cTqA==\";\n\t\"purchase-info\" = \"RXRjL0dNVCI7Cn0=\";\n\t\"environment\" = \"Sandbox\";\n\t\"pod\" = \"100\";\n\t\"signing-status\" = \"0\";\n}")
```

to

```
[]byte(`{\n\t\"signature\" = \"ZwXG56AezlHRTBhL8cTqA==\";\n\t\"purchase-info\" = \"RXRjL0dNVCI7Cn0=\";\n\t\"environment\" = \"Sandbox\";\n\t\"pod\" = \"100\";\n\t\"signing-status\" = \"0\";\n}`)
```

in golang? or is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Don't get it. It seems same. https://play.golang.org/p/s5twKzSrTUK 
output from base64encode.org:
{
 "signature" = "ZwXG56AezlHRTBhL8cTqA==";
 "purchase-info" = "RXRjL0dNVCI7Cn0=";
 "environment" = "Sandbox";
 "pod" = "100";
 "signing-status" = "0";
}

Comment: By the way your JSON is not valid. There should not be  semicolons `;` at the line endings.

Comment: @Lupus, actually, the result is different with https://www.base64encode.org/, please view my question, I have updated my question.

Comment: @ThunderCat, the json string is returned from apple store in-app-purchase logic. Which confused me is why `[]byte("....")` and `[]byte(`...`)` given the different result after `base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double quotes and backticks denote different string literals in Go: https://play.golang.org/p/wfIPUJtxT9n

In particular, backslashes are not escape characters when used with backticks; they are preserved. For instance, `len("\"") == 1` (byte 0x22), but `` len(`\"`) == 2 `` (bytes 0x5C and 0x22).

This is defined [in the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals):

> Raw string literals are character sequences between back quotes, as in `foo`. Within the quotes, any character may appear except back quote. The value of a raw string literal is the string composed of the uninterpreted (implicitly UTF-8-encoded) characters between the quotes; in particular, backslashes have no special meaning and the string may contain newlines. Carriage return characters ('\r') inside raw string literals are discarded from the raw string value.